# How to get single value from JSON response ionic 4

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

My json response is

```
{results: {…}, jsontoken: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJyZXN1bHQiO…I4NH0.KFEl7IKFCGgf8Lh-NrnJ6_kThQcTG9mi617CQRzmMEg"}
jsontoken: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJyZXN1bHQiOnsiaWQiOjExLCJ1c2VyX2lkIjoiOUJHM1BWS3h5MVdhYXFYMyIsIm1vYmlsZSI6IjAwMCIsIg"
results:
createdDtm: "8/7/2020"
id: 11
invitecode: "123"
mobile: "000"
updatedDtm: "8/19/2020"
user_id: "9BG3PVKxy1WaaqX3"
walletBalance: "110"
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
```

How to get single value from this object. Example how i get invitecode?

I tried
console.log(results.invitecode)  // result is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

invitecode is not under results. so you have to use

```
 body.invitecode
```

Comment: `this.auth.userData$.subscribe((res:any) => {
      this.authUser =  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res));
       console.log(this.authUser.invitecode);
    });`

Comment: are you sure console.log(this.authUser) print the json object you shared ?